# Can $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-a_{2n})=0$ ensure $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$?

Tags: limits

Can $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-a_{2n})=0$ ensure $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$? It seems difficult to find a counterexample. The often used  $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is not such one.

Comment: $a_{2^{n}}=0$ for all $n$ and $a_n=1$ when $n$ is not a power of $2$.

Comment: $a_n = \sqrt{\ln n}$

Comment: What about simply $a_n=1$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 1):

$a_n=1$ for all $n$ is a counterexample:  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n-a_{2n})=0,$ but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$.